# Technical difference between my home wifi and my phone wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, git

I'll try to describe my problem as good as I can.

Background:
I mostly work from home. I'm a freelancer and have two laptops, an ASUS laptop, now 3,5 years old, and a SAMSUNG, now 8 months old. Both run Windows 11 Home edition.
I have an internet connection with one of the major providers in the Netherlands, but switches early this year from another major provider. Both laptops connect over WiFi.

The good:
The ASUS laptop is fine.

The problem:
The SAMSUNG has problems connecting to Azure DevOps. When I do a git push I have to redo the command between 1-25 times before it succeeds. So it does succeed eventually, but in the meantime it gives the following error:
`fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/XXXX/': Recv failure: Connection was reset`

The solution:
When I connect the SAMSUNG to the wifi of my office (when I'm on site) or to my phone's access point everything works perfectly, it never fails.

What I've ruled out / troubleshooted:

- Provider: I switched from provider early this year. Problem remained.
- Set the SAMSUNG laptop forced to 2.4 Ghz band. Problem remained.
- Git / laptop config as it does work eventually, it has the same setup as the ASUS, and the problem does not happen when on my phone's access point. Removed and reinstalled git anyway. Problem remained.

I would like a solution to work with my SAMSUNG using my normal WIFI access. Does anyone has an idea on what more I could try

Comment: Try to disable IPv6 - [link](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/issues/1150).

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't find these sources. I've had these issued for 8 months. Removing IPV6 solved this and a few other issues.

Comment: The answer suggests this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230241/fatal-unable-to-access-https-dev-azure-com-xxx-openssl-ssl-connect-connec/69712045

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling IPv6 has solved this problem.

For more information see the bug-report
[fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/****/': Recv failure: Connection was reset #1150](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/issues/1150).